# Git remembers submodule's remote and history even after removing it

Tags: git, git-submodules

I followed [How do I remove a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule) to delete a particular submodule. However, if I try to add a submodule with a different remote at the same path, git ends up checking out the submodule with the previous remote.

For example,

1. git submodule add https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete path/auto-complete
2. Remove three lines for auto-complete from .gitconfig
3. Remove two lines for auto-complete from .git/config
4. git rm --cached path/auto-complete
5. git commit -a
6. git submodule add https://github.com/Sarcasm/auto-complete path/auto-complete

At this point, instead of fetching from remote2.git, I end up with remote1.git's checkout in path/auto-complete.

git remote -v in path/auto-complete still shows https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete for origin.

Comment: did you delete it from `.gitmodules` as well?

Comment: Yep. Turns out you have to delete it from .git/modules as well.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can now simplify the process with (git 1.8.3, April 22d 2013):

```
git submodule deinit
```

(See "[How do I remove a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309)")
You would still need to remove `.git/modules/yourSubmodule` though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found this in one of the other answers to the original question:

> In addition to the recommendations, I also had to rm -Rf
>   .git/modules/path/to/submodule to be able to add a new submodule with
>   the same name (in my case I was replacing a fork with the original)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9536504/288634